# Node.js/ express.js/ Backbone.js : req.body.keys is undefined?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, ecmascript-5

I'm using Backbone.js on the client side and express.js on the server, and I'm trying to save/put a model update via Backbone. I've done nothing to Backbone.sync, and so it should be just plain old $.ajax.

On the server, I've got a simple

```
app.put('my-url', function(req, res){
  req.body.keys.forEach( function(key){
    // do stuff with key
  });
});
```

Each time, I get an error message saying 'cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined, and sure enough a quick console.log shows that req.body.keys is undefined. Another quick couple of console.logs show that Object.keys and 'forEach' are just fine, that typeof req.body is object.

Anyone see what is going wrong? I tried JSON.parse(req.body) and got the famous 'unexpected token o' error...

Comment: Try `console.log(req.body)` to find out what is happening. You can even try `console.log(req)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is different:

```
Object.keys(req.body).forEach(function(key){ ... })
```

Comment: He said he got req.body.keys undefined

Comment: That's because `keys` is not a part of the Object prototype, it's on the constructor/Object namespace.  You pass in the object you want the keys for.

Comment: I assumed that he sent `keys` in the body of the request, like `{ keys: [1,2,3]}`. lol

Comment: doh! i had been using a homemade version up until now and I forgot to check the docs. Thanks @evilcelery!